# create custom input type range cross browser

Tags: css, html, range

I'm trying to customize the html5 input type=range tag using some css, so far I've made something using the webkit:

```
div#timeline input[type="range"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: darkgray;
    height: 2px;
        border-right: black solid 4px;
        border-left: black solid 4px;
}

div#timeline input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 16px;
    height: 8px;
    background: #696060;
}
```

however seems like that this only works with chrome, is it possible to make a custom slider so that is the same for every browser?
I was thinking about making something that will emulate the behavior of an input range, but I couldn't find anything online and I'm quite new with javascript and stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using some javascript library like jQueryUI or jQueryTools. The last one has pretty simple demos:

http://jquerytools.org/release-notes/index.html#form

Unfortunaly the input range can't be styled in a cross-browser way with just pure CSS right now, we need to wait a little bit more.

Comment: Thanks I used jquery ui. It s quite easy to customize and works on any browser